# buildroot for rpi, after enter make, returns error

Tags: linux, makefile, raspberry-pi, buildroot

When I buildroot for RPI, at the last step, as i enter make,
it returns an error,

```
jin@ubuntu:~/buildroot-rpi$ make
--2014-06-06 17:53:26--  http://www.metrological.com/rpi/arm-raspberrypi-linux-gnueabi_x86_64_gcc4.7.2.tar.gz
Resolving www.metrological.com... 199.27.74.175
Connecting to www.metrological.com|199.27.74.175|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-06-06 17:53:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2014-06-06 17:53:27--  http://sources.buildroot.net//arm-raspberrypi-linux-gnueabi_x86_64_gcc4.7.2.tar.gz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net... 176.9.16.109
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net|176.9.16.109|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-06-06 17:53:28 ERROR 404: Not Found.

make: *** [/home/jin/buildroot-rpi/dl/arm-raspberrypi-linux-gnueabi_x86_64_gcc4.7.2.tar.gz] Error 1
```

How to solve this problem, Thanks.

Comment: are you behind firewall, I got the same problem behind firewall, I used vpn to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the mainline Buildroot instead. It has support for RasberryPi, XBMC and many other packages. At least, you would have some support from the Buildroot community, which is not going to be the case if you use some random Buildroot fork.